# Why ld.exe cannot find certain files?

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

I recently installed network simulation tool omnet++. I am following the tictoc example given in the documentation. When i run the make command i am getting the following error. How can i correct this?
[image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happens as window antivirus treat netool.exe file as a virus as well some others windows antivirus do the same. 
disable the antivirus before build (make) the omnet++ will solve this problem.

Comment: @prashant_thakre problem solved...!! re-installed & configured omnet++ with antivirus disabled...it is working fine.